# container is not able to access other container port

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu-16.04, jupyter, iptables

I have a container that runs jupyter-hub on 443 and mapped to 1443 on the host. I'm trying to run this server behind the apache in another container. But, the two containers are not able to talk to each other.

I have tried setting the iptables for each container, but no use.

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state -s 172.17.0.2  --state NEW  -mtcp -p tcp  --dport 1443  -j ACCEPT
```

172.17.0.2 is the IP of jupyterhub container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a user defined network which allows containers to talk with each other.
When you do docker run, provide the network parameter with your user defined network. 
Please see a simple example below.

```
docker network create --driver bridge my_custom_network
docker run --network=my_custom_network -itd --name=container1 busybox
docker run --network=my_custom_network -itd --name=container2 busybox
docker attach container2
/ # ping container1
PING container3 (172.19.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.19.0.2: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.113 ms
64 bytes from 172.19.0.2: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.147 ms
64 bytes from 172.19.0.2: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.146 ms
64 bytes from 172.19.0.2: seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.146 ms
```

Below link provides more details: 
https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/#user-defined-networks

Answer (score 1):

The problem when the 2 containers not able to talk to each other is due to the fact that they are not in the same docker network. Here are what you have to do:

- List all the available networks: `docker network ls`
- Find out which network the `apache` container is running in

```
docker inspect <apache_container_id> -f "{{json .NetworkSettings.Networks }}"
```

- If `apache` container is in `host` network, create a new network and attached it to that container

```
docker network create apache_network
docker network connect apache_network <apache_container_id>
```

- Launch your `jupyter-hub` container in that same network `docker run ... --network apache_network ...`
- The 2 containers can not be able to talk to each other using their container name.

Try to use the DNS and not IP when dealing with containers as IP may change quite frequently.

Comment: Two containers are pingable each other but the problem is apache container is not able to reach out jupyter on 1443 port.

Comment: Because they are in the same network, apache server should reach jupyter container at port 443, not 1443. Only when you want to reach the jupyter container from your host machine then you will want to reach it at port 1443.

Comment: Which means apache container cannot reach out jupyter container?

Comment: If they are in the same network, `apache` container can reach out to `jupyter` container at port 443 like `curl jupyter:443`